# Ruby Code Formatter Atom Editor, Error spawn rubocop ENOENT?

Tags: ruby, editor, atom-editor

I have installed atom-beautifier.
When i try to format my ruby code i get the following error:

> spawn rubocop ENOENT

Comment: I have a windows system. but im sure that rubocop ist not in the PATH

Comment: https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-rubocop/issues/11